# Visual Studio 2017 template for Xamarin.forms and Azure B2C

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, azure-ad-b2c

Looking for the proper template in VS2017 for Xamarin. Forms app using azure B2C

Comment: template for what? Views , MVVM pattern, or you mean plugin?

Comment: Do I start with a Xamarin Forms or with an azure app services quick start app?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. I suggest to select Xamarin.Forms , then later link to Azure if needed'

Comment: Thanks for your comment.